# Show this $|\sin{x}|+|\sin{(x+1)}|+|\sin{(x+2)}|>\frac85$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality, convex-analysis, absolute-value

Let $x\in R$ show that
$$f(x)=|\sin{x}|+|\sin{(x+1)}|+|\sin{(x+2)}|>\dfrac{8}{5}$$

since
$$f(x)=f(x+\pi),$$it sufficient to show $x\in (0,\pi]$

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since $\sin$ is a concave function on $[0,\pi]$ and sum of concave functions is a concave function,

we have
$$\min_{[0,\pi]}f=\min\{f(0),f(\pi-1),f(\pi-2),f(\pi)\}=f(\pi-1)=2\sin1>\frac{8}{5}$$

Comment: I'm afraid it took me a while to understand the logic. But, I got there in the end. Nice!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: same for me. I got it this way: we may split $[0,\pi]$ in sub-intervals, over which the given function is concave. Since the original function is piecewise-concave, the wanted minimum is one of the given values. Am I correct?

Comment: why $2\sin{1}>\dfrac{8}{5}$ can you have proof by hand methods?

Comment: @communnites I posted. See now. Also, we can use the Taylor series.

Answer (score 9):

Drafting behind Michael Rozenberg's clever answer, appealing to the concavity of $\sin$ on $[0, \pi]$ quickly reduces the problem to showing the inequality
$$2 \sin 1 > \frac{8}{5} .$$
From [$\pi < \frac{22}{7}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80) we deduce $\frac{3 \pi}{10} < \frac{66}{70} < 1$, and so
$$2 \sin 1 > 2 \sin \frac{3 \pi}{10} = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{4}(1 + \sqrt{5}) > \frac{8}{5}.$$ The last inequality (which itself is a reasonably tight bound on the Golden Ratio $\phi$) follows from rearranging and squaring.

Comment: It's just beautiful! +1

Answer (score 5):

Drafting behind Michael Rozenberg's clever answer, appealing to the concavity of $\sin$ on $[0, \pi]$ quickly reduces the problem to showing the inequality
$$2 \sin 1 > \frac{8}{5} .$$

Then, from Maclaurin expansion, we have

$$ \sin 1 = 1 - \frac{1}{3!} + \frac{1}{5!} - \frac{1}{7!} + \ldots $$

Observe that the absolute value of each of these terms is decreasing, hence in this alternating sum, we may conclude that

$$ \sin 1 = 1 - \frac{1}{3!} + \left( \frac{1}{5!} - \frac{1}{7!} \right) + \left( \ldots \right) + \ldots > 1 - \frac{1}{3!} = \frac{5}{6} > \frac{4}{5}. $$

---

In particular, we could have strengthened the original inequality to

$$f(x)=|\sin{x}|+|\sin{(x+1)}|+|\sin{(x+2)}|>\dfrac{5}{3}.$$

Answer (score 2):

We'll prove that
$$\sin1>\frac{4}{5}$$ by hand.

Indeed, let $f(x)=\sin{x}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{x^7}{5040},$ where $x\in\left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right].$

Thus, $$f'(x)=\cos{x}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{24}+\frac{x^6}{720};$$
$$f''(x)=-\sin{x}+x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^5}{120};$$
$$f'''(x)=-\cos{x}+1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{24};$$
$$f''''(x)=\sin{x}-x+\frac{x^3}{6}$$ and 
$$f'''''(x)=\cos{x}-1+\frac{x^2}{2}=\frac{x^2}{2}-2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}=2\left(\frac{x}{2}-\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)\left(\frac{x}{2}+\sin\frac{x}{2}\right)\geq0,$$
which since
$$f''''(0)=f'''(0)=f''(0)=f'(0)=0,$$ says that $f$ increases.

Thus, $$f(1)>0$$ or $$\sin1-1+\frac{1^3}{6}-\frac{1^5}{120}+\frac{1^7}{5040}>0$$ or
$$\sin1>\frac{4241}{5040}$$ and since
$$\frac{4241}{5040}>\frac{4}{5},$$ we are done!

Comment: Here's an alternative: Since $0 < 3 \pi < 3 \cdot \frac{22}{7} < 10$, we have $$\sin 1 > \sin \frac{3 \pi}{10} = \frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{5} + 1) > \frac{4}{5},$$ where the last inequality follows from rearranging and squaring.

Comment: @Travis Post it. It's very nice!

Comment: I've just added the argument as a comment to your original answer, where it provides an answer to OP's follow-up question. Cheers!

Comment: @Travis The bounty was opened on the proof of $\sin1>\frac{4}{5}$ by hand. Post it. I think it must be your 50 points.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the bounty, I'll post it as you suggest.

Comment: I might be missing something. Can't we conclude directly from the Maulaurin expansion that $ \sin 1 > 1 - \frac{1}{6} > \frac{4}{5} $, since the alternating terms have absolute value $1/(2k+1)!$ hence is a decreasing sequence?

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to, but see my posted solution. Also, sin 1 = 0.841... > 0.833 ... = 5/6.

Comment: @Calvin Lin You are right of course. It's much more better. +1